# how to send right to left email using firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, right-to-left, nodemailer

I tried to use a welcome email to my users using firebase cloud functions. I am writing the email in arabic so the text direction should be right to left. The problem is that the text appears left to right how can I change its direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) can help you.
they have a special parameter for language.

```
https://example.com/usermgmt?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=ABC123&apiKey=AIzaSy...&lang=fr
```

you change the mode and lang to what you need. I strongly believe that if its RTL lang they make it RTL.

Comment: I am using java script not html